# How to send variables like {contactfield=id} in MAUTIC email campaign?

Tags: php, symfony, email, mautic

I want to send **{contactfield=id}** (one of the variable of the mautic) into custom headers for a mail that is to be used for a campaign. I am not sure of the right way to send it. I am keeping this variable into custom headers under **Channels > Emails** and selecting a particular email's advanced settings and into custom headers. This sets the *id* value of the first contact in the contact list of the segment selected for the campaign into all the remaining contacts. I want to get the dynamic value of each contact's id respectively. How can I get this appropriate result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify your problem and give some more details for it.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, not all of the fields in the Email builder can contain tokens. I remember that the Body and Subject allow it, but there were some other fields that did not allow it.

You seem to be getting the correct token, so if it's not returning in the header based on your testing, that field may not get parsed for tokenization on processing.

Comment: can we do some changes in code to achieve this? Can you let me know files where this code is executed?

Comment: how can we make any changes to the left sidebar of mautic ? Any leads to it ? I want to remove few menus from sidebar like calendar, companies etc. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ShivangTrivedi, are you creating a plugin in Mautic for that you need to add sidebar of anything else?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jordan Ryan, not all tokens are available under email, however the email object can be tapped by creating a custom plugin.

https://developer.mautic.org/#extending-emails
check out this section, it may help.

The second example on code block shows that you can place your custom placeholder and then replace it programmatically.

```
/**
 * Search and replace tokens with content
 *
 * @param EmailSendEvent $event
 */
public function onEmailGenerate(EmailSendEvent $event)
{
    // Get content
    $content = $event->getContent();

    // Search and replace tokens
    $content = str_replace('{hello}', 'world!', $content);

    // Set updated content
    $event->setContent($content);
}
```